# SUM for 3rd party table in many to many relationship

Tags: sum, many-to-many, relationship

I have a situation where I am bridging a 3rd party table between 2 other tables:

client (one-to-many) -> containers

containers -> containers_invoices (many-to-many) -> invoices

What I want is to get the SUM of the paid invoices for each client. The client is related to the containers, thus I have to connect the containers to the invoices and the clients to the containers to make the bridge. I used the following query to do so:

```
        $sql = "
        SELECT 
            SUM(invoices.invoice_eur) AS invoice_eur,
            SUM(invoices.invoice_usd) AS invoice_usd,
            invoices.status_id
        FROM containers_invoices
        LEFT JOIN invoices 
            ON containers_invoices.invoice_id = invoices.invoice_id
        LEFT JOIN containers 
            ON containers_invoices.container_id = containers.container_id
        WHERE containers.client_id = ".$client_id." AND invoices.status_id = ".$invoice_status."
        GROUP BY containers.client_id
        ";
        
        $x = $this->fetch_query($sql);
        if (isset($x[0]->invoice_eur)) $eur = $x[0]->invoice_eur . ' EUR';
        if (isset($x[0]->invoice_usd)) $usd = $x[0]->invoice_usd . ' USD';
        if (isset($x[0]->invoice_eur) && isset($x[0]->invoice_usd)) $spacer = ' | ';

        return $eur . $spacer . $usd;
```

here is an example of how the invoices should look like:

```
invoice 1 -> cont A, cont B -> 100 USD
invoice 2 -> cont A, cont B -> 7000 USD
invoice 3 -> cont A, cont B -> 75 USD
invoice 4 -> cont A, cont B -> 7000 USD

invoice 5 -> cont C -> 1000 USD
invoice 6 -> cont D -> 1000 USD
```

The issue is that when one invoice is made for 2 or more containers, the sum is calculated for each individually. In the case of invoice 2 the query sees it as 14000 USD because there are 2 containers. The solution is to introduce DISTINCT before invoices.invoice_usd and that solves the doubling problem, but then this approach is too aggressive because then DISTINCT looks at invoice 2 and invoice 4 (7000 USD) and sees them as double as well, and thus it skips invoice 4. The same happens for invoice 5 and 6 (1000 USD).

Is there a possible solution to this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's create the tables that are in the question here. For the sake of brevity, we'll use these abbreviations:

```
clid -> client_id
cid  -> container_id
inv  -> invoice_id
eur  -> invoice_eur
usd  -> invoice_usd
```

Let's create sample rows now:

```
containers
clid1, cid1
clid1, cid2
clid2, cid3

container_invoices
cid1, inv1
cid1, inv2
cid1, inv3
cid2, inv1
cid2, inv2
cid3, inv3

invoices
inv1, eur1, usd1
inv2, eur2, usd2
inv3, eur3, usd3
```

If we're to take the `JOIN` of these three tables on appropriate columns, a cross table that would be generated would look like this:

```
containers_container_invoices_invoices
clid1, cid1, inv1, eur1, usd1
clid1, cid1, inv2, eur2, usd2
clid1, cid1, inv3, eur3, usd3
clid1, cid2, inv1, eur1, usd1
clid1, cid2, inv2, eur2, usd2
clid2, cid3, inv3, eur3, usd3
```

As you can see in the table above, `row 1` and `row 4` are identical and `row 2` and `row 5` are identical as well. If we take the `sum` `group`ing only by `clid`, this would obviously double calculate the `inv1` and `inv2` entries for `clid1`. In order to only pick the legitimate values we can use `DISTINCT`. Here we would want this tuple `(clid, inv)` to be distinct (non-identical). Since `eur` and `usd` are columns of `invoices`. It is safe to assume we want `(clid, inv, eur, usd)` to be distinct (non-identical). So, the query would look like this:

```
select sum(invoice_eur) as invoice_eur, sum(invoice_usd) as invoice_usd
from (
    select distinct containers.client_id, invoices.invoice_id, invoices.invoice_eur, invoices.invoice_usd
    from container_invoices
    left join invoices 
    on container_invoices.invoice_id = invoices.invoice_id
    left join containers 
    on container_invoices.container_id = containers.container_id
    where containers.client_id = ".$client_id." AND invoices.status_id = ".$invoice_status."
) client_invoices;
```

Notice that you don't need to do a `GROUP BY` here since you already have a `WHERE` clause on `client_id`. See this [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jyoMCicNSZpjMt4jFYoz5/5583) for more clarity.

Comment: Thank you. You answer was the most complete one. Although I do require the GROUP BY client_id as I request this data in the client's page where I have another query that self joins itself for client's hierarchy. I did try the subquery approach, but I just didn't manage to get it right in my attempts. Thank you for the nice help, you are awesome! I will award the reputation when the stackoverflow timer allows me.

Answer (score 1):

**This can be achieved with DISTINCT.**

### How DISTINC works:

DISTINCT looks for distinct values in the specified column.
In the result rows which do not have a distinct value in the specified column do not show up.If multiple columns are specified in the select-statement **the value-combination of the specified columns have to be distinct** in order for the row to be counted as distinct.

### To your Example:

You select for invoice_eur, invoice_usd and status_id.
If you were to just add DISTINCT to your select statement all rows with distinct combinations of theese three columns will show up.
E.G. If you had one row with 
*invoice_eur: 100* 
*invoice_usd: 100* 
*status_id  : paid* 
and a second row with 
*invoice_eur: 100* 
*invoice_usd: 100* 
*status_id  : pending* 
both rows with show up. Even though invoice_eur and invoice_usd is identical for both rows, the combination of all three values is distinct.
**Solution for your problem:**
For your Invoice 5 and your Invoice 6 the values for all specified columns is identical. Therefore they are not seen as DISTINCT.
You can fix this by specifying another column that makes Invoice 5 and 6 discint. I would recommend invoice_id.
This makes sure that invoices that come up more than once (because they are in multiple containers) are still filtered out because the combination (invoice_eur, invoice_usd, status_id, invoice_id) is not distinct for these cases.
However you should not put DISTINCT infront of your SUM.
That way the SUM would be calculated first and DISTINCT would be applied on the result on SUM. SUM only gives one result(row) so this is pointless.
One way around this is a nested SQL-statement.

I recreated your database and the Query that works for me is this one:

```
SELECT 
SUM(invoice_eur) AS invoice_eur
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        invoices.invoice_id,
        containers.client_id,
        invoices.status_id,
        invoices.invoice_eur AS invoice_eur
    FROM dbo.containers_invoices
    LEFT JOIN dbo.invoices 
    ON containers_invoices.invoice_id = invoices.invoice_id
    LEFT JOIN dbo.containers 
    ON containers_invoices.container_id = containers.container_id) invoices_paid
    GROUP BY client_id;
```

You would only have to add rest of your select arguments and the WHERE-statement.

Comment: Thank you for the nice explanation, I do appreciate the effort you put in it!